# Tornado autoreload does not pass sys args

Tags: python, tornado

I have small Tornado app:

```
def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application(
        [
            (r"foo", Bar),
        ], autoreload=True
    )
```

which running in docker container.

Command to start `python -m api"` (api - project folder)

After autoreloading  I'm getting error:

`Argument expected for the -m option`

During debugging I found that parameter **api** is not passed.

How Can I solve that issue?

Comment: Which version of Tornado? This should work and it's how I normally run things.

Comment: last version - 6.0.3